# How do I list files which have a "s" as first and a "l" as last char with a shell-command?

Tags: command-line, bash, wildcards

I'm trying to list files that start with "s" and with "l".

The command I'm trying is `ls -l *sfa*`

Comment: @muru, after the edit the question is very confusing. The suggested command doesn't relate to the question. Dragonslayer, please clarify.

Comment: @laugh what's so particularly confusing about adding the [tag:command-line] and [tag:bash] tags? OP is using the command line, and the default shell is bash.

Comment: From your comment to cmks this is a homework question. We are not here to do your homework.

Comment: Homework typically comes with a textbook and a teacher. Have you tried looking into those ?

Comment: @muru - sorry, I didn't realize there was another edit before yours that changed the question text significantly. However "bash" is irrelevant here, wildcards are pretty much the same in all shells (and the OP may be using another shell - he didn't indicate bash).

Comment: @laugh Considering your own answer suggests brace expansion, don't dismiss the shell so easily. If the OP isn't using bash, then they should specify what they're using.

Answer (score 5):

The question is not very clear... based on your comment to @cmks, here are two options:

1. If you are looking for files where the first character of the filename is "s" and the last is "l" - then use `ls -l s*l`
2. If you are looking for files where the first character of the filename is (either "a" or "s") and the last is (either "a"  or "l") - then use `ls [as]*[al]`

If it's something else, please edit your question to clarify...

Your version `ls -l sfa` will only list files with the exact name "sfa" (or, if there's a directory with that name, any files in that directory). It doesn't do what you seem to be looking for.

---

The rules for matching file names ("globbing") are quite simple:

1. "?" matches any single character
2. "*" matches any number (zero or more) of characters
3. Use square brackets ([]) to match a single character from a collection: [fqsb] matches either f, q, s, or b; [b-d] matches b, c, or d
4. Use curly braces ({}} to match one of several specific strings: {foo,bar} matches either "foo" or "bar".

The directory separator "/" is excluded from matching - matching is only done on filenames.

See also [ShellGlobbing](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ShellGlobbing) in Ubuntu help.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -l s*l
ls -l s?l
```

- A "*" means 0 or more characters
- If you want an exact amount of letters between the "s" and the "l" a "?" means 1 char. 2 "??'s means 2 characters.
- You can also put collections in between []. So `ls -l s[a-z]l` would limit it to `sal` through `szl`

---

From comments:

If you want files beginning with "s" and "a" you can use a collection:

```
ls -l [sa]*
```

will list all files beginning with those 2 letters. You can use that to create all kinds of groups. Exampe [sa][df][1ojwfihwef]* would make it search for file beginning with 3 letters that each match that specific group

Answer (score 0):

You may give more than one parameter to the `ls` command at a time:

```
ls -l H* *l
```

What happens is, the shell does a `Pathname Expansion`. You may read more about it in the manual pages of bash:

```
man bash
```

Because the shell does it, the shell calls the command `ls` as follows:

```
ls -l Hejo Hesja Hejan Lesl Lesil Lesul Lestl
```

It is imported to understand, it is not the `ls` command but the shell who looks for matching pathnames.

Comment: Didn't work. I can do it this way tho, ls -l s* ; ls -l a* but i dont think my teacher would enjoy that.

Comment: That comment makes the question different than it originally was.

Comment: @Dragonslayer: Please give us a more precise hint what files you are looking for. What is the first char, what is the last, and what else should be repected. Three Supporter edited your post to clarify that, maybe they are wrong.

Comment: I agree with @cmks :-) and 1 addition: edit your question ;-)

Comment: Okay sorry, but i will try to clarify now.
I'm in a folder right now. Which i have the files Hejo Hesja Hejan och Lesl Lesil Lesul Lestl. 
I want to list every file that start with a H and ends with a l and i can accomplish it while doing ls -l H* ; ls -l *l but i dont know if i can combine them.

Comment: I edited your question as well as my answer. Last point that needs clarity: To you mean starting with a "H" AND or OR ending with a "l" ?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from using `ls` command and shell's wildcards, one could use `find` command as well.

```
$ find -maxdepth 1 -iname "s*l"                                                                       
./script.pl
./storm carl
./sal
./simple_curl
```